# Count only letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to count only the letters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in a list in alphabetical order without `Counter`?

For example, input:

```
['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']
```

Output

```
[['b', 1], ['l', 1], ['o', 2], ['r', 1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: How would you count a single string? Start with that

Comment: I might even start by making it a single string in the first place

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are letters. Use a nested loop through the list and characters, and increment the values in the dictionary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There're many ways of doing this without importing anything.
If you without .count().

```py
my_list = ['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
output = []

for letter in letters:
    count = 0

    for item in ''.join(my_list):
        if item == letter:
            count += 1

    if count > 0:
        output.append([letter,count])

print(output)
```

Do it without an increment counter variable.

```py
my_list = ['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

output = [[letter,''.join(my_list).count(letter)] for letter in letters if ''.join(my_list).count(letter)>0]

print(output)
```

Comment: I believe they're referring to: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Comment: both of these solutions are unnecessarily polynomial

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `str.count` and `star.islower` just use `str.join` first and sort it:

```
>>> data = ['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']
>>> combined = sorted(''.join(data))
>>> [[l, combined.count(l)] for l in combined if l.islower()]
[['r', 1], ['o', 2], ['l', 1], ['b', 1]]
```

Comment: @Jab -- maybe because the question specifically asks how to do it without Counter.

Comment: Ahh I didn’t see that I fixed it

Comment: I'm downvoting because calling `count` in a loop is a well-known antipattern

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
my_string = "".join(['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b'])
my_list = list(filter(lambda c: c in letters, set(my_string)))
my_list.sort()

result = {}
for i in my_list:
    result[i] = my_string.count(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import string

my_count = defaultdict(int)
my_list = ['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']

for list_item in my_list:
    for char in list_item:
        if char in string.ascii_lowercase:
            my_count[char] += 1

print(sorted([(k,v) for k,v in my_count.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Counter()` you can loop over all the letters and count them. You can leverage [`.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) to test if your character is a lowercase letter and `get()` to start the counts at 0:

```
l = ['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']

counts = dict()
for word in l:
    for letter in word:
        if letter.islower():
            counts[letter] = counts.get(letter, 0) + 1

print(list(counts.items()))
# [('r', 1), ('o', 2), ('l', 1), ('b', 1)]
```

This will be O(n) where n is the number of characters.

Comment: `.get(letter, 0)` makes a little bit more sense here

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga -- so used to using `setDefault` in other similar situations.

Answer (score -2):

The following snippet does exactly as asked, but in javascript.

Edit: Yes, this uses a counter in the Map

```js
function CountLetters(words){
   var min = "a".charCodeAt(0);
   var max = "z".charCodeAt(0);
  
   var letters = new Map();
   for(let word of words){
      for(let letter of word){
         let charCode = letter.charCodeAt(0);
         var boundsOk = charCode >= min && charCode <= max;
         if(!boundsOk){
            continue;
         }
         if(!letters.has(letter)){
            letters.set(letter,0);
         }
         letters.set(letter, letters.get(letter) + 1);
      }
   }
   return Array.from(letters).sort(function(a,b){
       return a[0].charCodeAt(0) - b[0].charCodeAt(0)
   });
}

console.log(CountLetters(['Bro', 'lo', '27', 'b']));
```